# Command to invoke menu-bar's open-file?

Tags: find-file, menus, gui, gtk3

The traditional way of opening a file is via `C-x C-f` (`find-file`). I don't know since when this has been the case, but in Emacs 27.0.50 (Linux), using the menu bar's `File` -> `Open File` invokes the GTK file selection dialog.

[image: GTK File Selection Dialog]

Since I prefer this behaviour, I'd like to know:

1. How can I invoke this GTK file selector via `M-x`?
2. What can I write in my Emacs init file so that `C-x C-f` opens this GTK dialog when I'm running Emacs on X Windows, but reverts to the traditional behaviour when running in the terminal mode?

Answer (score 3):

`find-file` uses the minibuffer or the GTK+ dialog depending on what [`next-read-file-uses-dialog-p`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/src/fileio.c?id=ba809612c06bcabd05dcbaae79da39dcb0925992#n5919) returns. So you can force the dialog by overriding this function:

```
(defun vf-find-file-with-dialog ()
  (interactive)
  ;; `flet' is deprecated, but I don't know enough Emacs Lisp
  ;; to make the non-deprecated `cl-flet' work here.
  (flet ((next-read-file-uses-dialog-p () t))
    (call-interactively 'find-file)))
```

Alternatively, here’s a hacky but perhaps more general workaround using [Zenity](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/):

```
(defun vf-find-file-with-zenity ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((name (string-trim-right (shell-command-to-string
                                  "zenity --file-selection 2>/dev/null"))))
    (unless (string-empty-p name) (find-file name))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You ask about initiation of the selection by `M-x`. I don't know whether there is a simple way to cause use of the dialog box even when you do *not* use a menu or tool-bar button (typically initiated with a mouse). (But it's also not clear to me what `M-x` has to do with selecting a file, unless you mean `M-x find-file` or some such.)

Anyway, the reason the file selection box is shown is likely because of the settings of options `use-file-dialog` and `use-dialog-box`, which you can customize.

In addition, since you have GTK, you can customize options `x-gtk-show-hidden-files` and `x-gtk-file-dialog-help-text`, which affect the behavior of the file selection box.

See the Emacs manual, node [Dialog Boxes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dialog-Boxes.html).

`C-h v use-file-dialog` tells us:

> **`use-file-dialog`** is a variable defined in `C source code`.
>   Its value is `t`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means *mouse* commands use a file dialog to ask for files.
>
> This applies to commands from menus and tool bar buttons *even when
>   they are initiated from the keyboard*.  If `use-dialog-box` is `nil`,
>   that disables the use of a file dialog, regardless of the value of
>   this variable.
>
> This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
>   version 22.1 of Emacs.

To your second question: You can test whether Emacs is running in a window system (GUI) or in terminal mode, using predicate `display-graphic-p`. `C-h f` tells us:

> **`display-graphic-p`** is a compiled Lisp function in `frame.el`.
>
> `(display-graphic-p &optional DISPLAY)`
>
> Return non-nil if `DISPLAY` is a graphic display.
>
> Graphical displays are those which are capable of displaying several
>   frames and several different fonts at once.  This is true for displays
>   that use a window system such as X, and false for text-only terminals.
>   `DISPLAY` can be a display name, a frame, or `nil` (meaning the selected
>   frame’s display).